# UILocalNotification on particular day like sunday repeat by every 2 week

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I want to repeat UILocalNotification particular day alternatively. I mean if it's fire on sunday 7:00 am then second notification should be fire on next to next sunday 7:00 am.

Is this possible?

Can any one help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a counter of hours's and save it in NSUserDefaults 
  `if (counterOfHours % 336 == 0)` then push notification, remember to set counterOfHours to 0 :)

Cheers S.

Comment: Can I keep running counter in while app is in the background ?

Comment: Or save 7:00 am sunday as [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[tempEvent.dateTo longLongValue]] timeIntervalSinceNow] and if saved number + 1 209 600 == [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[tempEvent.dateTo longLongValue]] timeIntervalSinceNow] it mean 2 weeks has passed